# Get HTML of new Chrome tab with Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, python-requests, python-webbrowser

I'm trying to scrape the HTML code of a new chrome tab, but I can't find a way that works using Python.

Here's what I've tried:

I've tried the `requests` module, but this code:

```
import requests

URL = "chrome://newtab"
page = requests.get(URL)

print(page.text)
```

Yields this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Ben Bistline\Code\PythonFiles\PythonFiles\chromescrape.py", line 4, in <module>
    page = requests.get(URL)
  File "C:\Users\Ben Bistline\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ben Bistline\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ben Bistline\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ben Bistline\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 649, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "C:\Users\Ben Bistline\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 742, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'chrome://newtab'
```

I suppose this result makes sense, but I'm not sure how/if I can get around it.

I've also tried using the `webbrowser` module with this code:

```
import requests, webbrowser

URL = "chrome://newtab"
chromePath = 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'

webbrowser.get(chromePath).open(URL)
```

Unfortunately, although successful, this method does not seem to offer a way of gathering the HTML.

Anyone know of any other ways using Python to grab the HTML of a new Chrome tab?

Thanks!

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Selenium driver](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) with Chrome to do that

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('chrome://newtab')
content = driver.page_source
browser.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, it doesn't seem to be working in any way. I have tried many different URLs, but all seem to open a new tab and do nothing. When I return to the IDE, the code unexpectedly crashes. Ideas? Should I post the problem?